# C++ Declarations

Tags: c++

I have a class, 'Cat', and a subclass of the Cat class, 'DerivedCat'. Cat has a function meow(), while DerivedCat overrides this function.

In an application, I declare a Cat object:

```
Cat* cat;
```

Later in the application, I initialize the Cat instance:

```
cat = new DerivedCat();
```

1. Which 'meow()' gets called? Why?
2. What are the advantages of declaring as the superclass type like this?
3. What is an example of where I would want to do this?

Comment: You can't do that. `new` returns a pointer, and `cat` is of type `Cat`, not `Cat*`.

Comment: This is homework. So show us you also try yourself a bit.

Comment: And if this is, by any chance, a homework question, you might be better served by going and reading in your textbook (or online, of course) about inheritance and virtual functions, than by simply asking us for the answer.

Comment: Sorry if it comes off that way, but it isn't homework. I'm just wondering why someone would want to call the subclass's constructor if the superclass's functions get called.

Comment: Then why is it tagged as homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant `Cat * cat;`, it depends on whether the meow method is virtual or not:

- If it is virtual, the definition in `DerivedCat` will be used.
- If it is not virtual, the implementation in `Cat` will be used.

In Java all non static methods are virtual by default. This is often what you want. However virtual methods can add a performance overhead at runtime to determine which implementation to call (e.g. a lookup in a [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)). Even if you never create a subclass you may still have to pay for this performance overhead. One of C++'s goals is to produce high performance code and therefore all methods are non-virtual by default.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm actually dealing with this code in a large system. This is just a simplified example. Why would I bother calling the subclass constructor if the code will just use the superclass's functions?

Comment: That explains a lot. 90% of my programming experience has been with Java.

Answer (score 1):

`cat` in your code is not a pointer or a reference, thus `cat = new DerivedCat();` calls `Cat::operator=(DerivedCat*)` on `cat`.

For this reason `cat.meow()` will call `Cat::meow`.

**EDIT** after OP's comment:

If `cat` was a pointer or a reference, you could make it point to your `DerivedCat` instance. In this case if you call a **virtual** `Cat` function that `DerivedCat` overloads, the version supplied by `DerivedCat` is called.

Polymorphism (which is this features you're asked about) is an important thing, it's at the base of Object Oriented Paradigm. It's not so easy to explain it with an example, I'd suggest you to read about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) or on [C++Faq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) for more implementation details.

Comment: Interestingly, the function is not defined as 'virtual'. Why would the author of this code bother using the subclass in the initializer if the instance is just going to call the superclass functions (provided in the declaration)?

Comment: @kwikness: maybe because there are other virtual functions in `Cat` and he could need to call one of those in future. Or maybe because `Cat` is a pure virtual class (ie: it cannot be instantiate). Or maybe because he needs that `DerivedCat` constructor's side-effects happen.

Comment: @kwik: `meow()` could call a private or protected virtual function. In fact it is sometimes considered good style not to have public virtual functions, see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm